# How to check if path is a folder or a file with svnlook?

Tags: svn

This is from svn docs(http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re44.html)

```
$ svnlook changed -r 39 /usr/local/svn/repos
A   trunk/vendors/deli/
A   trunk/vendors/deli/chips.txt
A   trunk/vendors/deli/sandwich.txt
A   trunk/vendors/deli/pickle.txt
```

I can check for trailing slash ("/") and if that exists, then it is a folder.

1) **But how can I make sure that svn will always display folder path with the trailing slash?**

2) Or, maybe there is more reliable way to check for path type(folder or file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there will always be a trailing slash on directory names as this signifies it is a directory. Otherwise it looks like a file without an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to parsing the output of `svn info` (Python + [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html)):

```python
from pysvn import Client, node_kind

client = Client()

def isDir(url):

    infoList = client.info2(url, recurse=False)
    _, info = infoList[0]

    return info.kind == node_kind.dir
```

In your specific case, since you are on the server, you can even use `file://` urls:

```
file://<absolute path to repo>/<relative path to file/dir within repo>
```

This way you won't go through the network layer -- which might save some time.

Answer (score 0):

Client side and assuming you have some kind of unix shell
You could cut the 'A' part away then simply test if the path is a directory using shell provided fonctions. something like

```
set TEST=`cat test.txt | cut -c5-`
for p in $TEST;do
 if [[ -d $p ]];then
   echo "$p is a directory"
 fi
done
```

Server side you can use:

```
svnlook dirs-changed REPOS_PATH
```

to detect the changed directories then filter them out of the change log from "svnlook changed" or you could use:

```
 svn info $PATH
```

on each path and check the node kind, though that's probably going to be slow.

Comment: I don't think this will work because I am using svnlook on the server inside of pre-commit hook. Those paths don't actually exists on the server

Comment: Oh sorry I hadn't noticed this was server side. you could use 
svn info
and check the Node Kind